# Connecting Visual C# 2008 to MS Access 2010 x64

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to connect to one of my MS Access databases in Visual C# 2008, problems is the MS Access 2010 is x64 and I'm using Windows 7 x64 and it doesn't see any Access driver for 64 bit architecture in ODBC, so my question is, is there any drivers available or fix for it or do I have to reinstall MS Access in x86?

I know I can use SQL for the database but would prefer to use Access as its easier for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you launching the x64 or x32 verison of the odbc manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Currently Microsoft does not have any 64 bit ODBC drivers available for the Office products.
However, as long as the application that you want to connect to is 32 bit, you can use the 32 bit ODBC drivers to create the DSN. To get to the 32 bit ODBC drivers, the 32 bit Data Source administrator must be used. The 32 bit Data Source administrator must be launched directly if you are using a 64 bit OS. The file should be located at the following path:c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe..."

From the following link : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-access/64-bit-driver-for-dsn-for-ms-access-database/be8c0ad4-d8fd-48e0-9026-b95d84135820

Comment: There is both a x32 and x64 version of ACE and drivers for Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You have to force your VS project(s) to use x86 processers:

double click the 
[image]

then set the Platform target

[image]